# Javascript - Send an array of arrays to a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have a function which return a list from  arrays. I call the function with an array of these arrays.

Here is the code :

```
<body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>



    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


        function getList(liste) {
            var control = ['resize', 'scroll', 'zoom', 'focus', 'blur', 'select', 'change', 'submit', 'reset'],
                    keyboard= ['keydown', 'keyup', 'keypress', 'input'],
                    mouse = ['click', 'dblclick', 'mousedown', 'mouseup', 'mouseover', 'mousemove', 'mouseout', 'mousewheel', 'wheel'],
                    all = control.concat(keyboard, mouse);


            console.log(liste);

            tab = [];

            for (var i=0; i < liste.length; i++) {
                    tab = tab.concat(liste[i]);

            }
            console.log('Array : ' + tab);

            return tab;
        } // End getList()

    console.log('Function return : ' + getList(['control', 'keyboard']));

    });



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

if i do a getList([control, keyboard]); I have an error because the browser don't know control or keyboard. Logic because they're local to the function. I i send these values with a ' the function return the parameters list in a string way.

I can't put the arrays definitions in global because I call this function from many places in many scripts.

In my example i should have

```
['resize', 'scroll', 'zoom', 'focus', 'blur', 'select', 'change', 'submit', 'reset','keydown', 'keyup', 'keypress', 'input']
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish your goal with an object that maps a name to a list. In the following code, `lists` is such an object. You can write either `lists['control']` or `lists.control` to get the list corresponding to the name `'control'`.

```
function getList(names) {
    var lists = {
        control: ['resize', 'scroll', 'zoom', 'focus', 'blur', 'select', 'change', 'submit', 'reset'],
        keyboard: ['keydown', 'keyup', 'keypress', 'input'],
        mouse: ['click', 'dblclick', 'mousedown', 'mouseup', 'mouseover', 'mousemove', 'mouseout', 'mousewheel', 'wheel']
    };

    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        result = result.concat(lists[names[i]]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

To use this function, make sure you write `getList(['control', 'keyboard'])` with single quotes around the list names.

An even nicer way to write the function is to make use of the `arguments` keyword. This lets you pass any number of names to the function instead of a list of names. Like so:

```
function getList() {
    var lists = {
        control: ['resize', 'scroll', 'zoom', 'focus', 'blur', 'select', 'change', 'submit', 'reset'],
        keyboard: ['keydown', 'keyup', 'keypress', 'input'],
        mouse: ['click', 'dblclick', 'mousedown', 'mouseup', 'mouseover', 'mousemove', 'mouseout', 'mousewheel', 'wheel']
    };

    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        result = result.concat(lists[arguments[i]]);
    }
    return result;
}

alert(getList('control', 'keyboard').join(', '));
```

You can see this running on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tro6dmb2/

Comment: Great the use of the object is a nice way

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that it will be suitable for your case, but maybe you should declare empty array in the beginning of `getList` like this `getListArray = [];`, assign returning value to it and then call `console.log('Function return : ' + getListArray);`. Note that `getListArray` is declared without `var` so it will be global and will be overwritten every time you call `getList`.